# How to separate posts into pages so that every page only has 10 items?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I generate a scaffold, in the index page, it lists all the data in the database. What if I only want 10 posts/page, and at the bottom there's a Page 1, 2, 3,... to click. Also, I don't want to retrieve all the data and use javascript to separate them into pages. I want to query exactly 10 posts and if someone click page 2 it starts another query.

Any ideas without plugins?

Comment: Checkout: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate or http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari?view=comments

Comment: What if I don't wanna use a plugin? How to write one myself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do paging of records with ruby on rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968015/how-do-i-do-paging-of-records-with-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Kaminari gem

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

and then set up your controller to response via JS, and use AJAX to update the page.

EDIT

If you want to write it yourself you could do this.

```
def index
   page = params[:page] ? params[:page] || 0
   @posts = Post.limit(10).offset(10*page)
   count = Post.count
end
```

Then in your view you would use the count to create a link for

```
/posts through /post?page=#{(count/10) - 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you have to use pagination, you can look on this 
https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate
http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari,
this is what the common people do and it will handle pretty good for you :)

you may take a look on this 
http://www.nullislove.com/2007/05/24/pagination-in-rails/
which you can roll up your own.